# SSH to AWS using keypairs and users?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I found this question: [SSH to AWS Instance without key pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119774/ssh-to-aws-instance-without-key-pairs) for how to disable the need to use keypairs on an EC2 instance.

I'd like to do something like that but if possible still use keypairs yet have multiple users. We'd like to give clients and vendors access to the server but don't want to share the same keypair with everyone.. is there a way to still use Keypairs yet have multiple user accounts to the server?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Found the answer: http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/73-Managing-Amazon-EC2-SSH-login-and-protecting-your-instances.html

Comment: This link is dead.  Can you elaborate on the relevant content in your answer?

Comment: Link is not working...A link is not an answer. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

I think the content of the dead-link can now be found as a Gist at https://gist.github.com/shauns/6229678

Comment: A link is not an answer , Kindly try to elaborate your answer with link as your support element. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer