# Setting up AWS instance as gitlab runner for ci

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have successfully installed gitlab-ci-multirunners on my AWS instance. However, during the configuration, i am asked of the password to the AWS instance and since I use a .pem file for authentication, I am unable to complete the runner configuration.

What would be the best approach to pass the .pem file in the configuration?

Comment: The link below answered my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119774/ssh-to-aws-instance-without-key-pairs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user with password and use it to run gitlab-ci-multirunner