# unable to connect to Ubuntu ami without using KeyPair

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have build an AMI in aws using

```
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0d77397e
```

Now I might be mis-understanding this, but I don't want to use a keypair as we are sharing this ami around a team. It is in a security group that is locked down to our IP's, so i just want to be able to log in using user/pass

When I try to connect I get the username prompt which I enter the user name Ubuntu in on pressing enter I get this prompt:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sharing keys you can create unix users like
1) sudo adduser username -- It will ask you enter password and other details
2) Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config setting
PasswordAuthentication yes
3) Restart the ssh daemon with
sudo service ssh restart

Now log back in by saying ssh username@ec2_ip and enter the password you just created in 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use key pairs ([multiple](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html), no need to share them), but if you really are resistant then you can [enable password logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119774/ssh-to-aws-instance-without-key-pairs).

Comment: thanks for the reply. If I want to add multiple keys, how do I add them to the machines? is this something I can do at build time?

Comment: Yes, you could create an EC2 instance with the user accounts you need and the corresponding public keys, then create an AMI from that image. Or you can just bootstrap the machines dynamically through cloud-init or a CM tool such as Chef. Here are some ideas: https://cloudonaut.io/avoid-sharing-key-pairs-for-ec2/

Comment: `cloud-init` or `Chef` is a way better solution. Rebuilding AMI every time team changes is not a viable solution.

Comment: Agreed, much better to do it dynamically.