# Best Way to manage AWS Access key ? So that when an employee leave the company . The employ should not be able to access the AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to know a way .

Assume there is an organization . There are many team which are using the EC2 resource and all the user have key that is required for the EC2 and now the employee leave the company . But he still have that Access key using which he can access it .

is there any best way to handle . AWS account permission so that when employee leave the company the access to aws account is denied .

Comment: Delete the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, only your root user should have root permissions in EC2 and should have to login using Key Pair, for any other employees one way is(and this is what I think is best for everyone)-

1. Create users for them inside EC2 (Don't give them root permission)
2. Create keyless entries with password authentication for those users.(Make sure you only allow **"PasswordAuthentication yes"** for your particular user that you might delete later)
3. Delete user when they leave

Here's a way to do Key-pair-less login:
[SSH to AWS Instance without key pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119774/ssh-to-aws-instance-without-key-pairs)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, so I'll start by clarifying a few terms.

An **AWS Access Key** (which looks like `AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE`) is associated with an **IAM User**. Think of it like a username when making API calls. It is accompanied by a Secret Key that acts like a password.

An Access Key and Secret Key is used when making API calls to AWS, such as requesting creation of an Amazon EC2 instance or sending a message to an Amazon SQS queue.

A **Keypair**, on the other hand, is used when connecting to a **Linux** computer (even outside of AWS). When using a command like `ssh`, a user can authenticate by providing the private half of a keypair. The receiving computer then compares it to the public half of the key pair which is stored in the user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If they match, the user is permitted to login.

When launching a new Amazon EC2 instance, you can specify a keypair. Software on Amazon Linux AMIs will copy this keypair to `/users/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` so that you can login to the instance. After doing so, it is recommended that you connect the instance to your standard corporate security system, such as Active Directory or LDAP. Continuing to use keypairs rather than AD/LDAP can be difficult to manage on an on-going basis.

So, to answer your question...

If you are referring to an **Access Key**, then simply **delete the IAM User** and their Access Key can no longer be used.

If you are referring to a **Keypair**, then in the best situation, access is managed with Active Directory or LDAP. If so, you can **disable the user in the directory**.

If, on the other hand, you are managing access by using the keypairs originally setup on the instance, then you will need to **go to every instance that has that keypair and remove it from the appropriate `authorized_keys` file**. Please note that a keypair is stored in a user directory, to there might be multiple users on an instance that have a copy of the keypair. If this sounds like a lot of work, then you now know why many organizations prefer using a central directory of users to manage security.